# Error: "export 'default' (imported as 'ClassicEditor') was not found in '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor5

Hi I've decided to try using ckeditor according with https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html but stucked with error:

```
"export 'default' (imported as 'ClassicEditor') was not found in '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'
```

I've also tried inline version and got similar error. Anybody knows how to fix this? I understand that seems library doesn't export module, but can't understand is it a bug or not.

Made a demo repo with a problem
https://github.com/woto/ckeditor_rails_react

clean steps reproducing guide https://github.com/woto/ckeditor_rails_react/commit/94f99385c4496d89d05de8ffff0d0123a757c57b

[image: ckeditor 5 react export default ClassicEditor]

[Also bug reported on a github](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/issues/88)

Comment: having same issue